# How to remove part of a div's left border

Tags: html, css

I have a picture with a transparent background that is overlapping on top of a div.

How can I remove the part of the div's border that overlaps with the picture?

Here is what I am looking for:

[image: Demonstration of what I am looking for]

Here is what I got so far:

```css
.task-border {
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px 5px 15px 57px;
}
.task-border span {
 font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.task-border p {
 color: rgb(117, 112, 112);
}

.diamond:before {
    content: '';
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    background: url("http://storage3.static.itmages.ru/i/16/0622/h_1466575194_5693746_71d457d34b.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    left: -4.7%;
    top: 10%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 task-border diamond">
  <span>Фирменный стиль</span>
  <p>это индивидуальность фирмы, вынесенная на обозрение.</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why did you make z-index :-1 on .diamond:before ? Just raise it a bit and it will be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `background:#fff` with image `url` and `z-index:-1` to  `z-index:0`...
It's work

```css
.task-border {
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px 5px 15px 57px;
    position: relative;
}
.task-border span {
 font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.task-border p {
 color: rgb(117, 112, 112);
}

.diamond:before {
    content: '';
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    background: url("http://storage3.static.itmages.ru/i/16/0622/h_1466575194_5693746_71d457d34b.png") #fff 0 0 no-repeat;
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: -32px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top:-32px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 task-border diamond">
  <span>Фирменный стиль</span>
  <p>это индивидуальность фирмы, вынесенная на обозрение. это индивидуальность фирмы, вынесенная на обозрение. это индивидуальность фирмы, вынесенная на обозрение.это индивидуальность фирмы, вынесенная на обозрение.</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: one problem, how to make a picture all the time standing on a vertical middle?

Comment: I have update the snippet. add `top:50%` and add minus top margin half height of your image like `margin-top:-32px`

Comment: Fantastic! I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: inadvertently drupal also know? =D

Comment: Sorry, i don't know. Can't help in Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited** Just added new css to  `.diamond:before{ background:#fff;}`
this is what you want?

```css
.task-border {
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px 5px 15px 57px;
 
   
}
.task-border span {
 font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.task-border p {
 color: rgb(117, 112, 112);
}

.diamond:before {
    content: '';
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    background: url("http://storage3.static.itmages.ru/i/16/0622/h_1466575194_5693746_71d457d34b.png") 0 0 no-repeat #fff;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    left: -4.7%;
    top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 task-border diamond">
  <span>Фирменный стиль</span>
  <p>это индивидуальность фирмы, вынесенная на обозрение.</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like indexing problem.

Just change `.diamond:before` css like this;

```
.diamond:before {
    content: '';
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    background: url("http://storage3.static.itmages.ru/i/16/0622/h_1466575194_5693746_71d457d34b.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: -4.7%;
    top: 10%;
}
```